# Amídala ou amígdala?

Tags: ortografia, uso-de-palavras

É comum se ver "amígdala" mas é comum se ouvir "amídala", e provavelmente por causa disso, "amídala" é também visto.

Algumas dessas duas está errada? É alguma variação de dialeto? Sinônimos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interessante a sua pergunta, Bruno.  Como brasileiro, respondo que as duas formas são aceitas aqui. **Na forma escrita vejo "amígdalas" bem mais frequentemente do que "amídalas".**  **Já na língua falada, raramente ouço o "g" ser pronunciado.**

Sua pergunta, por outro lado, me fez perceber algo estranho: como médico que sou (quando não estou aqui no SE) eu escrevo "amí**g**dalas" e não pronuncio o "g". Mas, talvez incoerentemente, não só escrevo como também pronuncio o "g" em amigdalite e amigdalectomia. E nunca havia percebido isso.

Answer (score 5):

O dicionário Priberam indica que a grafia [**amídala**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/am%C3%ADdala) é usada unicamente no português do Brasil, e acrescenta que neste caso, ambas as grafias são usadas (amígdala e amídala) para referir o mesmo conceito: as glândulas situadas na parte de trás da garganta.